# How to force users to supply command line parameters in Powershell and to prompt them to do it

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing

I want to force users to supply mandatory command-line parameters when running a specific script and to make sure that they mandatory supply all three parameters and if they do not supply all of them, or if any of the parameters is wrong, then to prompt them to do it or to exit the script. I am using the script bellow, but I am still struggling. Can you help?

```
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string]$dbusername="",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string]$password="",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string]$Machine=""
)

if ($dbusername -eq NULL) Write-Host "You must supply a value for -dbusername" -or 
if ($password -eq NULL) Write-Host "You must supply a value for -password" -or 
if ($Machine -eq NULL) Write-Host "You must supply a value for -Machine"
```

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? The fact you're using `param` with `Mandatory=$true` is enough to ensure powershell will assign values to the parameters, either by receiving them from the command line or prompting for them

Comment: If I miss to type any of the parameters, there are some errors presented by PowerShell in red, which users usually ignore. I want to have an if clause somehow combined with a Write-Host where to "force" user to either input the correct parameter, or to give up. Is this possible in PowerShell?

Comment: Of course, but you need to define what "correct" is... You will have to verify the input that is given and then re-prompt the user and overwrite the existing variable if needed

Comment: I would like to add that it's a VERY BAD idea to encourage people not to read or learn powershell error output.  Yes it looks weird the first few times you see it, but it's incredibly helpful and your users need to learn it.

Comment: Exactly, i.e. verify that the password exists (user did NOT simply pressed ENTER when prompted to enter the password) and that the password is correct (respectively the dbusername). Do you have any hints on how to do that?

Comment: You can use Attributes like `ValidateLength`for that

Comment: @Colyn1337 I fully agree with you, but this script will be run by some users to get some results for a query in SQL only, and I cannot force them to learn Powershell for that matter....

Comment: @GeorgeMihailescu No, but surely you can ask of them to read what the computer writes on the screen?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen - Corect! thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to omit the `Write-Host` outputs within your function and to validate the parameters using attributes, for example:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$dbusername,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$password,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [ValidatePattern("[a-z]*")]
    [ValidateLength(1,15)]
    [string]$Machine
)
```

`PowerShell`already provides a well-known mechanism for that which experienced user will benefit of. Take a look at [about_functions_advanced_parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743(v=wps.630).aspx) to find more attributes.

Comment: Your pattern match any string.

Comment: You are right PetSerAl, just wanted to provide some sample attributes.